# Explain RewriteCond with %1 in it

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Could someone explain the rewrite below please the last two lines in this Rewrite Condition please - I'm unclear what the %1 is actually doing ?

```
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%1} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) to look up the URL in a structure, defined elsewhere, called 'domainmappings'.  Look for that RewriteMap directive to get a better idea of what's going on.  The %1 refers to the value of the capture group (what's inside the first set of parentheses) in the regular expression.  Essentially this is just looking the URL up in a mapping table which is stored in an external file and then replacing the URL with the value from that file.